# Adding an ip address on startup

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ethernet, tunnel

I have a raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu Server running. I got it to start up. I am running an Ethernet cable directly from my laptop to the raspberry pi.

On my laptop, I manually set the Ethernet IP address to 169.254.26.3/16

In order to connect to the Ubuntu server on the raspberry pi, I run `ip address add 169.254.3.3/16 dev eth0`

This creates an inet address under the device eth0.

Then, I am able to connect from my laptop by typing `ssh ubuntu@169.254.3.3`.
Things work!

However, when I restart the Ubuntu server, the address I created is gone, so I have to create another one. This is where my problem is.. because I want to be able to turn on the server and connect from my laptop. The raspberry pi Ubuntu server will be headless, so there will be no info on a screen to see, and I will not have a keyboard to use either.

Comment: Look up how to use netplan to set up the network. An enormous number of easy examples are online.

Answer (score 0):

This could be performed by cron:

```
sudo crontab -e

@reboot /usr/bin/sleep 30 && /usr/bin/ip address add 169.254.3.3/16 dev eth0
```

But it is better to convert this command into a script, give it execution permissions and specify the full path to it in cron.

Here's `sleep 30` command specified to wait some time before that ip address creating for a case if system will not be ready to run IP address creation command at the moment.

Systemd also [could be used](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6). But it requires more actions to be preformed in this case.